# Spill-over function/calculation

Tags: java, function, vba, loops

I am looking for a function that will allow a cell/variable/index to fill up to a certain point but once that cell/variable/index passes the given threshold it will spill over and start filling the next cell/variable/index. I am working with Visual Basic (excel) but im sure I can translate an example function from java etc into what I need.

Basically I have mount points on a server and when the server storage reaches the 2TB limit, it creates a new mount point and splits the storage evenly between the two new mount points. However these amounts must be rounded based on LUN sizes:
Between 100gb & 1000gb = rounded to nearest 50gb (ie 100, 150, 200, etc.)
Between 1000gb & 2000gb = rounded to nearest 250gb (ie 1000, 1250, 1500, etc.)

An example of what I mean below I was trying to do this in a foreach loop but it isnt doing what I need (again this is excel vba):

```
For Each cell1 In rng1    
    If cell1.Value >= 4096 And < 6144 Then
        Range("x1") = cell1.Value/3
        Range("x2") = cell1.Value/3
        Range("x3") = cell1.Value/3

    ElseIf cell1.Value >= 2048 And < 4096 Then
        Range("x1") = cell1.Value/2            
        Range("x2") = cell1.Value/2

...
```

Comment: This is a very vague description. Do you have an example to show us what you mean?

Comment: I added a little more clarification to what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Your question still seems to have holes since the values you are checking are not what the question states but here is a concept to get you started.

```
Dim gig_disperse AS Integer
For Each cell1 in rng1 
   SELECT CASE cell1.value
      CASE 4096 to 6143
           gig_disperse = roundGigs(cell1.Value,250)
           Range("x1") = Round(gig_disperse/3,0)
           Range("x2") = Round(gig_disperse/3,0)
           Range("x3") = gig_disperse - Range("x1") - Range("x2")
      CASE 2048 to 4095
           gig_disperse = roundGigs(cell1.Value,50)
           Range("x1") = Round(gig_disperse/2,0)
           Range("x2") = gig_disperse - Range("x1")
   END SELECT
Next cell1


Function roundGigs(val As Long, gigs As Integer) AS Integer
    roundGigs = Round(val / gigs,0) * gigs
End Function
```